# How to update child's(from the created list) props from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This might refer to other relevant general questions like how to update a child component from the parent, though I'd like to hear any fair judgement of my design solution to the following scenario.

I have a parent class where I store css attributes for 2 children objects.

```
import React from 'react'
import Item from './item/Item'

class Small_gallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chosenVal: 0,
    };

    this.listObjParams = [
    // Style 1
      {
        left: 300,
        zIndex: 0
      },
     //Style 2
      {
        left: 320,
        zIndex: 1
      }
    ];

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.calculateShift = this.applyNewStyle.bind(this);
    this.listItems = this.listObjParams.map((objStyle, i) =>
        <Item
            key={i}
            id={i}
            objStyle={objStyle}
            onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
    );
  }

  handleClick = (indexFromChild) => {
    this.setState({chosenVal: indexFromChild});
    this.applyNewStyle(indexFromChild)
  };

  applyNewStyle = (clickedIndex) => {
   if (clickedIndex === 0) {
   // somehow I want to apply new css style 2 to the clicked? <Item> child
  };
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          {this.listItems}
        </div>
    )
  }
```

Child component is rather trivial:

```
class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              this.props.onClick(this.props.id)
            }}
            style={{
              left: this.props.objStyle.left,
              zIndex: this.props.objStyle.zIndex
            }}
        >
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The question is: how can I apply style 1 or 2 to the clicked Item component(depending on the index I am returning)? I've read about `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead of using deprecated `componentWillReceiveProps` here https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607 but it's not a solution for me.

I expect number of created Items to grow in the future to 10-20, so it makes no sense to populate state of Item with `this.listObjParams` when creating it, or am I wrong here?

Comment: So will the style for each item be 1 or 2? Do expect this to change over time or will it be hardcoded?

Comment: @Neil the style should change on the user click. The initial styles will be coming from the parent. So far they are hardcoded.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, when you click between these `<Item>`'s do you expect them to take on either `z-index` = `1 || 0`. So if there are 3, there is always going to be 1 select and others are inactive?

Comment: maybe my questions is not very clear either , just edited. So the idea is to change styles of components based on the clicked Item (the index is returned), there will be more Items in the future, this is just a simplified example of two @Neil

Comment: What items are you adding a list of something? The styles are basically a boolean, either yes or no based on selectedId. I get that. But what data are you looping over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working example below, so to cover what I did:

- Create a prop that takes an array of items, more items more looped `<Item />`'s will appear.
- Styles are either `activeStyles || inactiveStyles` it is based on the `currentId` matching the id from object (from array prop = `items`).

```
import React from "react";

const inactiveStyles = {
  left: 300,
  zIndex: 0,
  backgroundColor: "#E9573F"
};

const activeStyles = {
  left: 320,
  zIndex: 1,
  backgroundColor: "#00B1E1"
};

const inboundItems = [
  {
    id: 0
  },
  {
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  }
];

// Note - added to show it working not needed
const defaultStyles = {
  display: "block",
  border: "1px solid black",
  width: 50,
  height: 50
};

export const Item = ({ id, onClick, style }) => (
  <>
    <pre>{JSON.stringify({ styles: style }, null, 2)}</pre>

    <div
      {...{ id }}
      style={{ ...defaultStyles, ...style }}
      onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        onClick(id);
      }}
    />
  </>
);

export const SmallGallery = ({ items = inboundItems }) => {
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = React.useState(null);

  const getStyles = selectedId => {
    return currentId === selectedId ? activeStyles : inactiveStyles;
  };

  return items.map(({ id, ...item }) => (
    <Item
      key={id}
      {...{ id }}
      {...item}
      style={getStyles(id)}
      onClick={selectedId => setCurrentId(selectedId)}
    />
  ));
};

export default SmallGallery;
```

Let me know what you think, I added a screenshot to show styles being added.

[image: <SmallGallery /> working]

Comment: this looks interesting, I'm going to test it soon, thank you for your answer ! @Neil

Comment: @Ren no worries, let me know how you get on!

Comment: thanks @Neil , just had my hands on it. Your code seems to me more advanced, do you use newer react syntax? More specifically I don't see state initiation, and render functions. Anyway, your answer helped me to come up with the solution that finally worked!

Comment: Awesome glad the code helped!, yes it is just using stateless functions with the new useState() it is a functional way instead of using setState(). If you could mark as solution that would be awesome! 

Answer (score 1):

For `<Item/>` you can use simple functional component. Optimal for simple, not so complex use cases.

E.g

```
const Item = ({ id, clickHandler, objStyle }) => (
  <div
    onClick={e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      clickHandler(id);
    }}
    style={...objStyle}
  />
);
```

`PureComponent` will be updated on props change, too.

In full class component you can use `shouldComponentUpdate()` to force rerendering on props change. No need to duplicate data (into state) using `getDerivedStateFromProps` (depends on use case).

Search for some tutorials (f.e. typical todo examples) since you have no idea about state management, updating etc.

Placing `listObjParams` outside of `state` won't force rerendering on update. BTW it looks more like a style pool - maybe you should have a child params array... you can combine it with style index array or keep them (and pass as props) separately.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // chosenVal: 0, // temporary handler param? probably no need to store in the state
      listObjStyles: [0, 1] // style indexes
    };

    this.stylePool = [
    // Style 1
      {
        left: 300,
        zIndex: 0
      },
     //Style 2
      {
        left: 320,
        zIndex: 1
      }
    ];
```

usage:

```
this.listItems = this.state.listObjStyles.map((styleIndex, i) => <Item
        key={i}
        id={i}
        objStyle={this.stylePool[ styleIndex ]}
        clickHandler={this.handleClick}
    />
```

Updating `listObjStyles` (`setState()`) will force rerendering, updating `this.stylePool` won't (move to the `state` if rerendering required).

Of course `stylePool` can contain more than 2 styles for different item 'states'. You can make styles for selected, liked, unliked - by storing indexes in an array you can mix any of them with custom logic (f.e. only one selected, many liked).

10-20 items is not the case where you need special optimizations (other than avoiding unnecessary rerenderings).

Comment: thanks for your answer @xadm. could you please elaborate on the style pool, I think it's close to what I need

Comment: Updated, writing handler to update `listObjStyles` array element is up to you. F.e. you can use `map` to allow only one selected (accordion style).

Comment: some troubles with how to bind this context when I have my map function above... ```this.listItems = this.listObjParams.map((objStyle, i) =>
        <Item..```

Comment: thanks @xadm, it worked with this context, could you please explain why? I also had to put mapped iteration directly to the render() as I show in my answer, otherwise it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just to sum up what I've done to make it all work based on two answers (still a rather toy example):

Parent:

```
import Item from './item/Item'

class Small_gallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listObjStyles: [0, 1]
    };

    this.stylePool = [
      {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: 600,
        left: 300,
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        zIndex: 0,
        transition: 'all 1s ease'
      },
      {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: 600,
        left: 720,
        height: 350,
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        zIndex: 1,
        transition: 'all 2s ease'
      }]
}

  handleClick = (indexFromChild) => {
    console.log(indexFromChild)
    if (indexFromChild === 0) {
      this.setState({
        listObjStyles: [1, 0]
      })
    } else if (indexFromChild === 1) {
      this.setState({
        listObjStyles: [0, 1]
      })
    }
}
render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div style={{display: 'flex', margin: 40}}>
          {this.state.listObjStyles.map((styleIndex, i) =>
              <Item
                  key={i}
                  id={i}
                  objStyle={this.stylePool[styleIndex]}
                  onClick={this.handleClick}
              />
          )}
        </div>
      </>)
  }
}
```

Child:

```
const Item = ({id, onClick, objStyle}) => (
  <div
    onClick={e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      onClick(id)
    }}
    style={{...objStyle}}
  />
);

export default Item
```

Comment: The problem with your code, is that your click handler is only going to get bigger. You also don’t need manage state like that. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also are you hardcoding the stylePool every time you want another positioned div?

Comment: @Neil you're right, somehow binding of this context is not needed here for handleClick function. Can you explain why? What I'm trying to achieve is to simply change two css div container styles (positions is one of the properties changed), based on the item clicked. e.g. if clicked on the 0th element, get the 1st element style with animation, and vice versa. But, as mentioned before there will be more items (like 10-20) so the algorithm how to assign these css styles from the Style pool is not done yet. 2 childs are just for example here.

Comment: So when you click on the 0 index you want to animate the index = 1. So what is the scenario when you have 5 items in the list and you click on index = 6?

Comment: Bind rationale (from free code camp): https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/amp/